# dayjs returns wrong date with format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert a date to a readable format.

For example:

```
var dayjs = require('dayjs')

const date = '1989-08-12T01:00:00.000Z'
console.log(dayjs(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

The result shows: **11/08/1989**

Expected behavior
A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen.

I expect that the log should return **12**/08/1989 instead of **11**/08/1989

[Day.js](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) Version: v1.8.16

Not sure if I miss any parameters or not. Thanks,

Comment: Try `date = '1989-08-12'`. What will be the result?

Comment: Your problem is your timezone `.format` format with your timezone. use `.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:m:s')` and see log, you will understand

Comment: I think the problem is `utc` time difference.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov it returns 12/08/1989. I guess, it is one way to solve it. About UTC time, can you elaborate that? I'm reading about too.

Comment: @Hongarc it shows 11/08/1989 9:0:0. Time is different...?

Comment: No, it is the same.  `'1989-08-12T01:00:00.000Z'` is time of GMT, `11/08/1989 9:0:0` is time in your location (timezone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input is timezone 0, but the output is your timezone.
You can change your code to

```
var dayjs = require('dayjs')

const date = '1989-08-12T01:00:00.00' // remove 0Z
console.log(dayjs(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Your problem is the same with https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/323

Comment: Thanks @Hongarc. This could be a solution.