# dayjs format method returns one day off and gives me a wrong date

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, date, dayjs

When I fetch data from my PostgreSQL database, it comes in the following format: `2022-11-30T21:00:00.000Z` and it's not a string; it's in the form of a date object.

The library that I'm using to work with dates is `dayjs`. So here is the issue.

When I call the format method, I get a bad date. like one day off.

dayjs('2022-11-30T21:00:00.000Z') and it gives me `2022-12-01T00:00:00+03:00`.So the real date that was stored was 30th November, but it gives me 1st December.

I saw this post [dayjs returns wrong date with format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491212/dayjs-returns-wrong-date-with-format) in Stack overflow but the accepted solution is wired because it assumes that I manually remove the `Z` at the end.

And even when i try to convert it in a `YYYY-MM-DD` by using `dayjs('2022-11-30T21:00:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD')` it's returning `2020-12-01`.

I really stuck.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the library converts the time to the local timezone. In this timezone (UTC+3), the time happens to fall on a different date as well. If you want to keep the original date, you have to tell dayjs to use UTC instead of the local timezone.

As the [library's docs explain](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone), you can customize which timezone you use for the parsing/converting. For this, you have to add the timezone and UTC plugins. For example, in the browser:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
```

```js
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);
```

Once you add the plugins, you can get the correct and formatted UTC days in this way:

```js
dayjs.tz("2022-11-30T21:00:00.000Z", "UTC").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You can see the complete solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bnsv0ytj/).

Answer (score 1):

The date conversion is correct. The given date is 0 UTC and the output is +3 UTC. Since the time provided is 21.00, the converted date with +3 UTC is the next day at time 00.00

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dayjs `utc` like this:

```js
dayjs('2022-11-30T21:00:00.000Z').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); //or whatever date format you want
```

If you set `utc(true)`, it will return Dec 1 instead of Nov 30.

Source: https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/utc#docsNav